# How to config package.json for vscode_extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, deno

In vscode_deno exist one line

```
  const exePath = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration(EXTENSION_NS)
    .get<string>("path");
```

exePath default is null , How should to config for exePath in package.json?

Comment: I think the config should be set in .vscode/settings.json

Comment: You're using Deno. There is no package.json. Get Node out of your head.